# registered users in 2 databases in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database

i would like to ask about code in asp.net. 
I am trying to display the information for a user that is registered in 2 different database. 
if the user is registered in the first database and the second database it will display his/her information. (go to h2)

if the user is registered in the in the first database and he/she is not  registered in second database it will display registration page. (go to Hreg)

and if he/she is not registered in the  first database it will display an alert message indicate that the is not existed in the first database.

the code is running will but for the condition  where the user is existed in both databases is not working . Hreg page is shown instead of h2.

this is the code in c#.
Thank you

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["BID"] = B_id.Text;

            SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["firstDB"].ConnectionString);
            conne.Open();
            String checkuser = "select * from WU where ID=@ppid";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conne);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ppid", B_id.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            var pid = Session["BID"];


             if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["secondDB"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from Patients where PID=@pid", conn1);
                conn1.Open();

                if (pid == cmd1 )
            {
                Response.Redirect("H2.aspx");
            }
                else
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('not registered')</script>");
                }
             conn1.Close();

            }
              conne.Close();
            SqlConnection conne1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["firstDB"].ConnectionString);
            conne.Open();
            String checkuser2 = "select * from WU where ID=@ppid";
            SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(checkuser2, conne);

            com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ppid", B_id.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            da1.Fill(dt1);

            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                SqlConnection conn11 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["secondDB"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from Patients where PID=@pid", conn11);
                conn11.Open();


                if (pid != cmd2)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("HReg.aspx"); 

                }

                conn11.Close();

            }
      conne1.Close();






        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is almost same as your code, you haven't specified the parameter value in the first If.

BTW you don't need to manually open and close connections while working with SqlDataAdapter, it do this for you.

You are getting data from both the DB twice in this code, you should combine them in one to improve the performance (reduce overhead).

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

        Session["BID"] = B_id.Text;

        SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["D"].ConnectionString);

        String checkuser = "select * from Students where Id=@ppid";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conne);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ppid", B_id.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        var pid = Session["BID"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from Students where Id=@pid", conn1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid);//Missing in your code
            conn1.Open();
            if (cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString() != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("H2.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('not registered')</script>");
            }
            conn1.Close();
        }
        SqlConnection conne1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataConnection"].ConnectionString);
        String checkuser2 = "select * from Students where ID=@ppid";
        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(checkuser2, conne);
        com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ppid", B_id.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        da1.Fill(dt1);
        if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SqlConnection conn11 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from Students where PID=@pid", conn11);
            conn11.Open();
            if (pid != cmd2)
            {
                Response.Redirect("HReg.aspx");

            }
            conn11.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you i tried your code it was helpful but still the problem doesn't solve it always show h2 . whether the user is registered in DB2 or not. –  Asma 4 hours ago

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, have you noticed we are using: var pid = Session["Bid"] without casting, try cast it to your Id type.